# What is the correct Tag usage in ASP.net Core? TagHelpers vs HTML Helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

Since the release of ASP.Net Core, Asp team is pushing the use of TagHelpers more than the HTML helpers.

While scaffolding view from controller, ASP.Net Core creates add, edit page with the use of TagHelpers, But if you notice the index page they use old HTML helpers.

```
//Ex:
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Package)
    </th>
```

It is very confusing to understand what the ASP.net Core Teams agenda. Does anybody know which is correct way of doing this in ASP.net Core? My guess is that `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Package)` will be marked as deprecated soon. Please explain?

Comment: As I understand it, TagHelpers' biggest benefit is the code's readability. HtmlHelpers will not be removed from the framework I think, as these are basically just extension methods, which can be easily reproduced anyway...

Comment: Check this comparison [from the official docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro.html#tag-helpers-compared-to-html-helpers)

Answer (score 6):

Not every Html helper has an equivalent Tag helper. For instance, there is no equivalent Tag helper for `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Property)` or `@Html.EditorForModel()`. It makes sense because `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Property)` and `@Html.EditorForModel()` doesn't really output an HTML tag.

So use Tag helpers in favor of Html helpers if there is an equivalent. Otherwise, use Html helpers.

I don't think `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Property)` will be marked as deprecated (nor will any other display templates or editor templates such as `@Html.EditorForModel()`). These will continue to be used in ASP.NET Core.

Also, you might be interested in this thread regarding a TagHelper equivalent to Html.DisplayNameFor: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2387

Answer (score 5):

Tag Helpers are a new feature in MVC that you can use for generating HTML. The syntax looks same like as HTML but its processed by Razor on the server. Tag Helpers are in many ways an alternative syntax to Html Helper methods but they also provide some functionality that was either difficult or impossible to do with helper methods.

You can find some comparision : https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro.html#tag-helpers-compared-to-html-helpers

You can get more details for Tag Helpers: https://dannyvanderkraan.wordpress.com/2016/04/19/asp-net-core-1-0-goodbye-html-helpers-and-hello-taghelpers/

Answer (score 4):

According to that thread,

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3003

it seems like for the moment DisplayNameFor is here to stay and that there is no Tag Helper for your solution.

They mention `<label asp-for="blabla"></label>` a lot but this is not the same.

Answer (score 3):

I think tag helpers is the way to go, it is more readable, cleaner and can be used to create more complex tags that simulate the user controls in web forms days